# Limit backrefs to each chapter in per-chapter bibliography

Tags: biblatex, subdividing, back-referencing

If I cite a source in both Chapter 1 and Chapter 2 the back-ref list of the Chapter 1 bibliography will also contain the entry for the respective page in Chapter 2 (and viceversa). Is there a way to limit the backrefs to each chapter? Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,refsegment=chapter, backref,
backend=biber]{biblatex}
\defbibheading{bibbook}[\bibname]{\chapter{#1}}
\defbibheading{subbib}[\refname\space\chaptername\space
  \ref*{refsegment:\therefsection\therefsegment}]{%
  \setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}%
  \section{#1}}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter
\chapter{First}
\textcite{glashow}

\chapter{Fooo}
\textcite{glashow}

\backmatter
\printbibheading[heading=bibbook]
\bibbysegment[heading=subbib]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `refsection`s instead of `refsegment`s.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,refsection=chapter, backref,
backend=biber]{biblatex}
\defbibheading{bibbook}[\bibname]{\chapter{#1}}
\defbibheading{subbib}[\refname\space\chaptername\space
  \ref*{refsection:\therefsection}]{%
  \setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}%
  \section{#1}}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter
\chapter{First}
\textcite{glashow}

\chapter{Fooo}
\textcite{glashow}

\backmatter
\printbibheading[heading=bibbook]
\bibbysection[heading=subbib]

\end{document}
```

[image]